# img.on("load") executes after the img is loaded but before it has its size set (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

**EDIT** : Added jsfiddle

- (for) https://jsfiddle.net/x60bwgw7/4/
- (each) https://jsfiddle.net/v3y2v8cf/3/
- **open in IE**, output values of 30 are wrong (IE placeholder height)
- I tried to return DOM naturalHeight and clientHeight, and while naturalHeight works properly in IE, clientHeight (the one I need) does not.
- Here's an obvious workaround, but it kinda sucks https://jsfiddle.net/0rhjt0wn/1/
- Seems like the problem is that IE renders image **after** it is loaded, while other browsers render it **while** it is being loaded, but Im just guessing here.

I've some images, that I want to load by assigning their "data-src" attribute value to theirs "src" attribute and vertically center them after.

It works without a problem in all browsers except IE (tested from 8 to edge).

In IE some images get centered without a problem, but some wont and it is because code in the **.on("load")** event gets executed (probably) after the image is loaded, but before it gets its size set.

**Is there any way to always execute the code after the image is loaded and its size is set (in IE)?**

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    targetSrc = $divElement.eq(i).children(imgClass).attr(dataSrc) + "?v=" + datetime;  

    $divElement.eq(i).find(imgClass).attr("src", targetSrc).on("load", function()
    {
        $holder.append($(this).attr("src") + " || height = " + $(this).height() + "<br>");
    });
}
```

Comment: How about doing this using **CSS** ???

Comment: Is that ok for you? : http://jsfiddle.net/yyj8ouae/

Comment: Cant use css and cant use each - original script is way more complex and for loop is necessary. if(this.complete) also doesnt help. This snippet is very simplified, original script loads only images that are currently in the viewport on window.load, scroll, resize and other events.

Comment: Can't use CSS or each because you have multiple elements with the ID `divElement` it seems, which is very bad.

Comment: In original script those are classes - my bad I'll edit it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially thought `requestAnimationFrame` and a timeout fallback could easily solve this but it turned out to be a lot more complicated. Apparently the exact frame at which an image is rendered after onload is not very predictable in IE. But I eventually came up with this solution that checks the `naturalHeight` against the current height to see if an image has been rendered, looping through to the next display frame when it is not the case yet :

https://jsfiddle.net/r8m81ajk/

```
$(function() {

    if (window.requestAnimationFrame) var modern = true;

    var element = $('.divElement'),
    reference = '.imgElement',
    holder = $('.holder'),
    datetime = Date.now(),
    path, image;

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    var target = element.eq(i).children(reference),
    path = target.data('src') + '?v=' + datetime;

    target.one('load', function() {

        image = this;

        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        nextFrame(image);
        });
        else setTimeout(renderImage, 50);

    }).attr('src', path);
    }

    function nextFrame(picture) {

        var dimension = $(picture).height();

        if (dimension == picture.naturalHeight) {
        holder.append('height = ' + dimension + '<br>');
        }
        else nextFrame(picture);
    }

    function renderImage() {

        holder.append('height = ' + $(image).height() + '<br>');
    }
});
```

The fallback will always check on the third frame (when there's no bottleneck). Don't mind I adapted the code a bit to my usual conventions, the external references should have remained the same.

From the question I realise the loop might not even be needed and getting `naturalHeight` when the image loads would be enough. Interesting exercise to detect the exact point of rendering in any case.

Comment: I ended up using my workaround (https://jsfiddle.net/0rhjt0wn/1/) because I have static width on my images, but your solution seems to be working. Note: naturalHeight/Width doesnt work in IE8 and bellow (but Im coding for IE9+ so w/e).