# Why am I not getting image width and height after loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an image element. I let user upload an image.
After upload, I process the image. I want to load the processed image and show it.
I am getting and show the image just fine.

I also need to know the width and height of the image loaded.

I am doing this correctly as below and it should work but not sure why I get width and height as zero:

HTML:

```
<img id="photo" src="">
```

JS:

```
    var id = 1000;
    var img = $("#photo").attr('src', '/photo/get/' + id)
     .on('load', function () {
          var w = 0;
          var h = 0;
          if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth === "undefined" || this.naturalWidth === 0) {
              alert("Could not load image");
          }
          else {
              alert('Image loaded');
              w = $(this).width();
              h = $(this).height();
              alert("width=" + w + " height=" + h);//PRINTS 0, 0, WHY???
          }
   });
```

Comment: Does this happen with all browsers? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32606323/3168107

Comment: Are u sure image loads correctly? This https://jsfiddle.net/82mkom0q/ displays dimensions in IE, FF and Chtome correctly

Comment: The loads correctly in my app. I see the image just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQueryObject.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) will return the computedStyle of the targeted element.
If in your CSS you force the `width` and `height` values of this element, then it will return those forced values.

What you need, if you want to get the size of the loaded image, is to check the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties of your `<img>` element :

```
w = this.naturalWidth;
h = this.naturalHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways,
Your way:

```
var img = $("#photo").attr('src', '/photo/get/' + id)
     .on('load', function () {

Output: Nothing.
```

using *.load()*:

```
var img = $("#photo").attr('src', '/photo/get/' + id)
     .load( function () {

Output: Nothing.
```

using *.ready()*:

```
var img = $("#photo").attr('src', '/photo/get/' + id)
     .ready( function () {

Output: "Could not load image".
```

So it didn't work.  Maybe something buggy there.

But when I used,

```
var img = $("#photo").attr('src', '/photo/get/' + id)
     .on('click', function () {

Output: "Image loaded";"width=280 height=160".
```

It worked perfectly given the proper Height and Width.
There's buggy something in on("load",) or load() not in your code.

P.S. *jQuery: ver:1.11.3. Browser: IE:11.0, Firefox:40.0, Opera:32.0*